# Any simulator for Microchip microcontroller for Linux distributions?

Tags: simulation, linux

I am making a project that involves Microchip PIC, I was wondering if there is a simulator software for it in which I can make circuits involving PIC?

I am using latest Arch Linux with KDE 5

It should look something like this:
 [image]

Comment: There are several possibilities which you might find using a web search on [simulator for pic microcontroller](https://www.google.com/search?q=simulator+for+pic+microcontroller&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8, but the details are off-topic.

Comment: @ThomasDickey of course I did websearch, I tried KTechLab but cannot install since it is unmaintained for years, tried couple of others too, but they all need to be build from source and I am finding difficulty in it

Comment: "It should look something like this:" *shows Proteus* Have you tried Proteus?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It is last option for me because it is not available for linux distros

Answer (score 1):

How about SimulIDE?
In my opinion this it is a very complete software, it has a lot of components including different PIC's and you can load firmware (binaries) to them
[image]

It's pretty easy to install
There is a package in the AUR (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/simulide) so you can install it using your package manager
For Arch: `sudo pacman -S simulide`
For Ubuntu: `sudo apt install simulide`